# Custom module to send scheduled messages in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

How to design a custom module that will send the message to the **receiver** as per the schedule time set by the **sender**?

Erlang and ejabberd are new to me. After going through the tutorials http://metajack.im/2008/08/28/writing-ejabberd-modules-presence-storms/ ,
http://anders.conbere.org/2008/07/17/building_ejabberd_modules_-_part_2_-_generic_modules.html ,
http://anders.conbere.org/2008/08/06/building_ejabberd_modules_-_part_4_-_xmpp_bots,
few chapters from http://learnyousomeerlang.com ,  http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/ i have come up with the following crude design.

From the sender's side,

1. the sender can either send a new "type" of stanza with the message and the schedule info encoded in xml attributes and then sent to the ejabberd server or
2. the sender can add another schedule xml attribute tag to the "message" stanza. Which of the two methods is preferable or are there any other better alternative?

A filtering module which uses **filter_hook** to stop sending the "scheduled messages" to the receivers and start a process that will search the "Mnesia" database for scheduled messages
(or "schedule" type stanzas) and set the timer based on the schedule parameter. Once the timer time outs the message is taken out of the "Mnesia"database and send
to the **receiver**.("I am assuming the messages are stored in the "Mnesia" database for later retrieval. Please correct me if this is not the case)

Another module that uses **user_available_hook** which should start a process that will search the "Mnesia" database for scheduled messages(or "schedule" type stanzas)
and set the timer based on the schedule parameter. Once the timer time outs the message is taken out of the "Mnesia"database and send to the **receiver**. This module is to handle
the "scheduled messages" sent while the receiver is offline.

But this design most probably will reduce the peformance since the "Mnesia" database is searched very frequently. Any better alternatives or advices to design such a module ?

**Edit 2: More description on the actual problem**
The idea is to add a feature to the xmpp client where the **sender** can control when the message should be delivered(example: sending the greetings for birthday in advance but it will be delivered to the **receiver** only on the birthday) instead of sending the message immediately.

Comment: Can you please clarify and describe the function you are trying to achieve. Possibly, you could simply write an XMPP bot to perform your task.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Added more description of the problem. Hope it clarifies. Regarding the XMPP bot, are you suggesting to write a XMPP bot that will filter and save the "scheduled messages" to Mnesia and will start a process for each "scheduled message" that will wait for the time out expiration to send the "scheduled messages" to client and die.